# @font-face issues

Tags: cross-browser, css, font-face

I am having some issues with loading a custom font on a site that I am working on.

Seems to work in Chrome, but that is it...

https://andstones.site-ym.com/

I attach a custom stylesheet,

```
<link charset="utf-8" type="text/css" href="http://www.korymathewson.com/fonts/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and in the stylesheet I write:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: ChunkFiveRegular;
    src: url('Chunkfive-webfont.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('Chunkfive-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('Chunkfive-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Chunkfive-webfont.svg#webfontb5K2fJwj') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I call that as a font-family..

```
h1.fontface {
    font: 60px/68px 'ChunkFiveRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0;
}

p.style1, #MainMenu {
    font: 18px/27px 'ChunkFiveRegular', Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

But it still does not show up in firefox or IE ... any help or advice you can lend?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that there was the up arrow, and the checkmark. Appreciate the bluntness :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox only allows embedded fonts that are on the SAME DOMAIN as the site requesting it. There is a (sort of) workaround here:

http://openfontlibrary.org/wiki/Web_Font_linking_and_Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing

You might want to try to use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to allow you to have the fonts themselves embedded in the CSS -- very useful!

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I ended up using cufon in the mean time for  a workaround as I did not have direct upload file access to they remote server. 

Great answer btw.

Answer (score 2):

What is `92p`? A node or is it meant to be a class? CSS class/id names can't start with a number.

Comment: good catch, this was my input error, but the actual stylesheet didn't contain the 92p... 

It is corrected in the post above.

Any ideas on the font-face?